# Nginx / Django. Excluding path from fastcgi_pass?

Tags: php, django, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to configure nginx to pass to django fcgi, but exclude certain paths from routing into django, and have one path be routed into a PHP fcgi. I'm having trouble getting the config right.

Here's an example of my vhost config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name awesome.com;
  #main django fcgi pass
  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8025;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
  }
  #alias for django static
  location /static {
    alias /var/www/django/awesome/django/static;
  }
  #alias for django media
  location /media {
    alias /var/www/django/awesome/django/media;
  }


  #Below is what I'm trying to figure out.


  #alias /vanilla to generic nginx file serving
  location /vanilla {
    alias /var/www/html/vanilla;
  }

  #pass the PHP scripts for vanilla forums to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location /vanilla/?*\.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Anyone have to do anything like this before? I'm not sure exactly how to get this configuration right.

Comment: what is the behavior with this config ? every request sent to django ?

Comment: yeah every request is going into django, the /static and /media alias workd fine, but I'm trying to get the /vanilla paths to work properly. It continues to get routed to django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `~*` modifier to do a case-insensitive (or `~` for case-sensitive) match to the regular expression:

```
location ~* ^/vanilla/.+\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: This works properly if the URL is "awesome.com/vanilla/index.php", but for some reason the "awesome.com/vanilla/" isn't properly using the index for php. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try moving `index index.php index.html index.htm;` above the location block?